# In xaringan, how to change the margin under flextable title?

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, flextable, xaringan

Let's say I have the following xaringan document:

````
---
title: "Test"
author: 
  - "me"
date: "2022-06-20"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, ninjutsu]
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```{r table, tab.cap="Iris", echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

iris %>%
  head() %>%
  flextable() %>%
  theme_booktabs()
```
````

which renders like this:

[image]

Now I wish to change the spacing between the flextable title and the table itself. What should I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea where the settings to be changed are defined, but when changing them, the extra space disappears... It needs to be done in css and the properties to set to 0 are 'margin-block-start' and 'margin-block-end'.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: 
  - "me"
date: "2022-06-20"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    css: [default, ninjutsu]
    seal: false
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---

```{css}
p {
  margin-block-start: 0px;
  margin-block-end: 0px;
}
```


```{r table, tab.cap="Iris", echo=F, warning=F, message=F}
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

iris %>%
  head() %>%
  flextable() %>%
  theme_booktabs()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

My own additions to [David Gohel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72713938/13511545):

After editing `margin-block-start` and `margin-block-end`, there will still be some gaps left in between the caption and the table, like this:

[image: table with caption margin]

My guess from checking the code is that the HTML rendering of `flextable` requires `tabwid.css`, which can be located by entering `system.file(package="flextable", "web_1.1.0", "tabwid.css")` in R console.

In `tabwid.css`, it reads:

```
.tabwid table{
  border-spacing:0px !important;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  line-height:1;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
  border-width: 0;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 1.275em;
  margin-bottom: 1.275em;
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

The `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` values are the reason of the remaining gap between caption and table. I edited these values in element inspector to see the effect:

[image: table with caption margin, inspected in browser]

[image: after changing margin values in inspector, the gap between caption and table is gone]

As far as my very limited knowledge goes, there's no way of changing the `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` of `.tabwid table{}` other than editing `tabwid.css` in the package itself. (adding a `{css}` block in rmarkdown script doesn't work)

Then again, for the sake of development simplicity and aesthetics, it might be a horrible idea to touch that file on my own.

Comment: I can make a parameter to allow its setting :)